# Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. Modified truffle.js not solving the problem

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

[image]

My smart contract could not deploy successfully, it contain 400 line. My truffle.js was configure to

```
module.exports = {
     // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
     // to customize your Truffle configuration!
     networks: {
          ganache: {
               host: "localhost",
               port: 7545,
               network_id: "*" // Match any network id
          },
          devops:{
            host:"localhost",
            port:8545,
            network_id:"4224",
            gas: 4700000        }
     }
};
```

But my smart contract is successful deploy in ganache but when comes to private blockchain it had error. 
May i know any limit size of smart contract to allow deploy to private blockchain?? and what is the way to check my size of my smart contract did it exceed the limit??

Comment: Please check the logs of your Geth node ( or parity ) if you didn't specify a log file check out these docs for Geth. after that post the logs related to the transaction of smart contract creation.

Comment: Also, please specify which private blockchain you are talking about ?

Comment: Get command options : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

Comment: It is possible the contructor is failing and that causes the revert. Is your private testnet enabled with bizantinum opcodes?

Comment: my smart contract is deployed to private ethereum blockchain,which is using geth

Comment: i deployed using truffle, but im just beginner, may i know how to check about log file??

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it causes by truffle without real problem with contract or configuration, usually removing `build` directory solves the issue.

Comment: i will try and see

Comment: tried cannot ><